# How does "var=>(...) somecommand" work?

Tags: bash, process-substitution

```
  #1   
   f() {
        cat "$1" >"$x"
    }
  #2   
    x=>(tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]') f <(echo 'hi there')
```

In #2 which part is executed first? `x=>(tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]')` or f `<(echo 'hi there')` . Is #2 is a compound compound or a single command?

Comment: In general, by the way, storing process substitution handles in variables is not particularly safe. The FIFO closes as soon as the redirection for the process substitution leaves scope (in this case, that scope being a single command), making the handle no longer usable.

Comment: ...if you run `{ ...multiline block here...; } 3>( ... )`, then you *know* that your process substitution will be in-scope, and available on FD 3, for the entirety of the block. Much better practice than futzing with variables and needing to worry about the variable scope and the process substitution's scope differing.

Comment: (What you're doing is safe *here* specifically because the assignment is part of a single command, not a compound command, and it's scoped to the single command within which the process substitution is guaranteed to remain available; if you made it `x=>(tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'); f <(echo 'hi there')`, two separate commands, you'd see that change: The variable would still be available, but the process substitution would no longer be running).

Comment: ...err, in my comment above, that should have been `{ ...; } 3> >(...)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A single command can have any number of `var=value` prefixes; these variables are exported to the environment for the duration of that single command, and do not exist later. This isn't bash-specific, but is part of the POSIX sh standard.

"Which part is executed first?" isn't a meaningful question. The process substitution whose FIFO's filename (being a `/dev/fd` entry and an anonymous FIFO if the OS permits same) is stored in X is *started* first, but execution is asynchronous. (That said, because the output of the process substitution writing `hi there` is redirected as input for the one running `tr`, the one with the `echo` necessarily blocks until `tr` is ready to read what it's writing).